# Check if url that belongs to the same domain exists in list with python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I wrote a script that parses some entered url on Outgoing links presence. What exactly i need is to check if entered url exists in the list of Outgoing links of specific tag. I do next:

```
from lxml import html
import urllib2
url = 'http://businessinsider.com/'

Testurl = urllib2.urlopen('somequerryurl' +url).read()
tree = html.fromstring(Testurl)

#this check if specific <li class=""> id tag exists
Elements = tree.xpath('//div[@id="bd-cross"]//li[@class=""]')

try:

    if len(Elements) > 0:
    links = list(tree.xpath('//li[@class=""]//a/@href'))

        if url in links:
            print 'Yes'
        else:
            print 'No'
    else:
        print 'No'
except ValueError:
    print 'Check your entered url!', url
```

For example i've got a list that contains http://www.businessinsider.com/2007/11/blablabla; http://www.businessinsider.com/2012/news/blablaba. Script gives me 'No' 'cause url(based on script) not in links - but the correct 'Yes'. What is the best way to check if url that belongs to the same domain exists in list in order to get right result?

Comment: Do you want to find if `http://www.businessinsider.com` is in ONE of the links in the list, or if it is in ALL of the links in the list?

Comment: i want to check if 'http://www.businessinsider.com' is in one of the list links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use the `list()` function, because it is a list already.

You can't check directly if the substring is in the list - you have to check each item in the list to see if the substring is in that item.

You could try:

```
links = tree.xpath('//li[@class=""]//a/@href')

found = False

for link in links:
    if url in link:
        found = True
        break

print found
```

You can make it shorter with:

```
any(url in link for link in links)
```

The `any()` function checks if any of the items in a sequence are true.  `url in link` is the test, and `for link in links` is an iteration.  I'm not sure if this is clearer unless you know a bit of python though.

Comment: It gives to me No. If i print a list it contains:    `['http://www.businessinsider.com/2007/11/facebooks-beaco', 'Computers/Internet/On_the_Web/Online_Communities/Social_Networking/Facebook/', 'search?q=u%3Ahttps%3A//www.businessinsider.com/&start=0&cat=/Top/Computers/Internet/On_the_Web/Online_Communities/Social_Networking/Facebook&all=no']` So after check url in list it return - No but 1st element of a list contains http://www.businessinsider.com/2007/11/facebooks-beaco what is exactly the same domain.

Comment: Yep. It gets to me Yes for 1st element. The output is: Yes, No, No. How can i print only Yes If url is contained in at least 1 element of a list? Because it will print output for every element of a list/

Answer (score 2):

Your `url` is `http://businessinsider.com/` and this is not part of the links you are given back, which contain `http://www.businessinsider.com/`.

You need to search for the domain itself:

```
>>> 'businessinsider.com' in 'http://www.businessinsider.com/foo/bar/zoo'
True
```

In order to avoid hardcoding it, you can parse the domain part:

```
from urllib2 import urlparse
url = 'http://businessinsider.com/'
search_domain = urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname

if search_domain in 'http://www.businessinsider.com/foo/bar/zoo':
   print 'Yes'
else:
   print 'No'
```

Here is a further example:

```
>>> urls = ['http://www.businessinsider.com/hello/foo',
'http://google.com/',
'http://businessinsider.com/']
>>> search_domain = urlparse.urlparse('http://businessinsider.com/').netloc
>>> for i in urls:
...    if search_domain in i:
...       print "{} contains {}".format(i,search_domain)
... 
http://www.businessinsider.com/hello/foo contains businessinsider.com
http://businessinsider.com/ contains businessinsider.com
```

Comment: Thank you! As i understand .netloc parses url. But it doesn't useful when you have a list with elements (in my case elements -  outgoing links).

Comment: You are not parsing the url of the links, you are just making sure that you are checking `businessinsider.com` and not the full string `http://businessinsider.com/` in the list of links. Your problem is not with the `for` check, its with the variable `url`.

Comment: thanks for example @BurhanKhalid ! one more question! What if e.g. `search_domain = '566.com'` and list contains `list = ['http://www.work566.com', 'http://566w.com/bla']`. It will return to me `http://www.work566.com contains 566.com`. But `http://www.work566.com` is different domain. How to prevent such situations?

Comment: You need to then parse the domain part as well from the links urls.

Answer (score 0):

[**pip install tldextract**](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/)

```
import tldextract

my_main_url = "https://cnn.com"
domainname = tldextract.extract(my_main_url)[1] # "cnn"
raw_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a [@href]')
for link in raw_links:
            l = link.get_attribute("href")
            if str(tldextract.extract(l)[1]) == domainname: #if link matches cnn
                print("this link's domain matches my_main_url: {}".format(l))
```